Is there a way to create a SEM from multiple datasets?
I have two datasets of information on a certain plant species, for which I would like to check if they are correlated.
One dataset is of visitor (pollinator) frequencies to a plant species along an elevational gradient (4 elevations). I have seven values of visitation frequencies for each elevation, these were obtained from seven 24-hour recordings of a plant individual. No plant individual was recorded more than once.
The other dataset is of seedsets produced from hand pollination experiments of plant individuals from the same species under various experimental treatments (autogamy (A), geitonogamy (G), control (C) and outcrossing (O)). In each elevation I have 15 seedsets from each treatment. The plants on which the hand pollination was carried out were different than those which were recorded. The hand pollination was carried out on the same species, but different individuals than were recorded. No plant individual was sampled more than once.
I would like to check, whether elevation has an effect on visitation frequency, and if visitation frequency in turn has an effect on the seedsets of flowers under various treatments. Also I would like to check, if the interaction between elevation is stronger via the visitation rate of visitors or without it.

Is there a way to run an SEM, which would be able to incorporate both of these datasets? A thing I could do would be to summarize the visitation rate per each elevation into and average and incorporate said average into the seedset dataset into a new column "visitation rate". However this would mean that instead of seven values, I would have only one per elevation, which would lead to elevation and visitation rate to be correlated and elevation would almost certainly explain the visitation rate. Alternatively, the same could be done for the dataset with visitation rate and inserting an average of each treatment into the dataset in four new columns.
What I am looking for is a way to keep both the variability of the visitation rates along with the variability of the individual seedset under various treatments. Is it possible to create a SEM model in which the model could be created from multiple datasets?

By "same species", do you mean that the exact same plants are present in both datasets (e.g. Plant 205 is in Dataset A and Dataset B)?

No, I did not mean that. By same species I mean, that the experiment was carried out on species Senecio p.. The dataset with visitation rates was carried out on plant individuals with ID 1-7 in each elevation, wheras the dataset with seedsets was carried out on plant individuals with ID 50-... in each elevation. So the plant individuals in the visitatio  dataset are different from those in the seedset dataset

You're using a structural equation model, which to me indicates that you are trying to assess causality of structural relationships between variables. I could be wrong, but that doesn't seem possible with your dataset. If you have one dataset with one set of flowers and another dataset with another, one cannot make any reasonable causal connections between both sets of flowers unless there was something about the flowers in Dataset A that were causing some change in the flowers in Dataset B. If Dataset B's flowers were descendants of Dataset A's "parent" or something like that, then we could perhaps establish some causality. You need something that causally connects the two, and that can only happen if they have something shared in their structural relationships.
To give a non-flower example, suppose we have Hospital A with humans and Hospital B with humans, both with a certain number of floors. The first hospital has recorded visitations of patients. The second hospital has patients that are unrelated to Hospital A's patients that are treated a number of ways (chemo, herbal therapies, etc.) Can we infer a relationship between the two? There may be some non-zero correlation between visitations in Hospital A and B, but they're likely spurious. We also can't make any connection between the floors on Hospital A and the outcomes of people in Hospital B. So this wouldn't really make sense to do.
The other thing which is confusing about your design is that you are treating the treatments as outcomes. This should really be some kind of factor variable that explains some outcome, which doesn't appear to be modeled correctly based off the path model you illustrate in your question.
I could perhaps have some confusion about what it is exactly that you are trying to structure, but to me SEM doesn't immediately look to be a solution to your problem.
